# Modal Behavior Problems

Tags: html, modal-dialog

I have put together a page that uses three modals. The first one seems to be working fine while the second two do not. For some reason they will appear for a second and then link to a website that has an href below. The code all appears to be the same to me and I cannot for the life of me determine why this is happening. Any advice or insight would be much appreciated, I am sure to an experienced programmer the solution would be obvious.

Thanks for any assistance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scal=1">
  <title>Jesse Stiff's Portfolio</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
 </head>
 <body> 
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <img class="udacity-logo img-responsive alt="Logo"" src="http://cameronwp.github.io/cpcom/static/udacity_logo.svg" width="150" height="150" alt="Udacity Logo">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
    <h1 class="title-super text-thin">Jesse Stiff</h1>
    <h4>Front-end Ninja</h4>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="hr">
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://s20.postimg.org/hubmpqrfh/Main1200x400.jpg" alt="Jesse Coding Image">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2 class="text-muted marginleft">Featured Work</h2>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://s20.postimg.org/7zkhjinh9/SAP300x200.jpg" alt="Resume Image" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project1">
    <h3 class="text-uppercase">Resume</h3>
    <p><a href="https://reddit.com">Project Link</p>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://s20.postimg.org/rip2svm8t/Arcade300x200.jpg" alt="Arcade Game Image" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project2">
    <h3 class="text-uppercase">Classic Arcade Game</h3>
    <p><a href="https://reddit.com">Project Link</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://s20.postimg.org/j61rh6gkd/Springfield300x200.jpg" alt="Neighborhood Map Image" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project3">
    <h3 class="text-uppercase">Neighborhood Map</h3>
    <p><a href="https://reddit.com">Project Link</p>
   </div>
  </div>
   
   
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="project1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Resume</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://s20.postimg.org/7zkhjinh9/SAP300x200.jpg">
        This will be a Description of my online resume once it is completed.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="project2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Classic Arcade Game</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://s20.postimg.org/rip2svm8t/Arcade300x200.jpg">
        Here is the awsome classic arcade game I have not yet created!
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="project3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Neighborhood Map</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://s20.postimg.org/j61rh6gkd/Springfield300x200.jpg">
        Here is an amazing neighborhood map I created!
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the logo's `img` tag there are two closing `"` in the first `alt` attribute (`alt="Logo""`). By the way I think the first one is unnecessary.

```
<img class="udacity-logo img-responsive alt="Logo"" src="http://cameronwp.github.io/cpcom/static/udacity_logo.svg" width="150" height="150" alt="Udacity Logo">
```

The real problem that you mentioned is related to the missing closing tags. You open an `<a>` tag for all the 3 `Project Link` text but you never close these tags. Here you can see that.

```
<p><a href="https://reddit.com">Project Link</p>
```

It will be correct if you close before the closing `</p>` tag.

```
<p><a href="https://reddit.com">Project Link</a></p>
```